# При запуске программы вылезает исключение System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: "Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию",

Tags: c#, sql-server, исключения

При запуске программы вылезает исключение System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: "Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию", подскажите как это исправить.
Код:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Lab_9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CreateDatabase(string sqlQuery)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("create database " + sqlQuery, connection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    outStat.Text = " база данных успешно создана!";
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    outStat.Text = " ошибка создания базы данных!";
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddTable(string tableName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("create table " + tableName + " ( " + tableName + "_ID Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1))", connection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    outStat.Text = " таблица успешно добавлена!";

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               outStat.Text = " ошибка добавления таблицы!";
            }
        }

        private void AddColumn(string tableName, string columnName, string type)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("alter table " + tableName + " add " + columnName + " " + type, connection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    outStat.Text = "Статус: столбец успешно добавлен!";
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    outStat.Text = "Статус: ошибка добавления столбца!";
                }

            }
        }

        private void DeleteColumn(string tableName, string columnName)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("alter table " + tableName + " drop column " + columnName,
                        connection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    outStat.Text = "Статус: столбец успешно удален!";
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    outStat.Text = "Статус: ошибка удаления столбца, возможно имя задано не верно!";
                }
            }
        }
        
        private void butNewDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateDatabase(NameDB.Text);
        }

        private void butNewTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddTable(nameTable.Text);
        }

        private void butNewRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddColumn(nameTable.Text, nameRow.Text, inpVar.Text);
        }

        private void butDelRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeleteColumn(nameTable.Text, nameRow.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Исключение появляется во время выполнения этой строки:

```
private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Appi.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <connectionString>
        <add name = "DefaultConnection"
             connectionString ="VladPC\SQLEXPRESS; 
             Initial Catalog = testDB; Integrated Security = True"
             providerName ="System.Data.SQLClient"/>
    </connectionString>
</configuration>
```

Comment: connectionString**s**

Comment: Спасибо за помощь